# Accessing String Collection in JSP (Application Scope vs Session Scope)

Tags: java, jsp, enums, scope

Okay, so basically I have an enum:

```
public enum A {

    A, B, C, D;

    public static final Collection<String> displayColl = createDisplay();
    private static Collection<String> createDisplay() {
        // Convert enum to acceptable String display magic here... 
        return ImmutableCollection.copyOf(string collection);  
    }
}
```

I would like to access this collection on a JSP as menu options.  I have the following four options, and would like to know which one I should use and how...

1. Place the collection in a `ServletContext` attribute and access it on the jsp by calling `${application.StringDisplayCollection}`.
2. Rip off an immutable copy of the collection whenever I need it and store it in the session, then access it on the jsp through the session scope.
3. Convert the collection to JSON and get it via ajax whenever needed on page load up.
4. Some cool way I haven't thought of that would be better and/or simpler...

Thank you and let me know if you need any clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion:** Place the collection in a ServletContext attribute and access it on the jsp by calling ${application.StringDisplayCollection}.

Not in session scope because this doesn't change on a per user/session basis.

Comment: Okay cool.  Other than immutability, do you have any suggestions for implementation? Should I have one class that holds all of the collections, such as ${application.DisplayClass.StringDisplayColl}, or just call ${application.EnumName.StringDisplayColl}? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write a static method with an String input (class name) and a Collection result, then define your static method as EL function in a .tld file. So you can have something like: **${fx:enumItems('EnumFullyQuallifiedClassName')}**.